# need help replace function javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML site and have to replace a string in it.
The code looks like this:

```
<div class="field field_text field_name_manufacturer_key_number field_value_50-000">    
    <div class="label">    
        Herstellerschlüsselnummer   
    </div>
    <div class="label">    
        50.000    
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to only change the string above "Herstellerschlüsselnummer" and the rest have to be untouched

With JavaScript looks like this but it doesn't work and I don't know why

```
document.getElementsByClassName("field_name_manufacturer_key_number")["0"].innerHTML.replace('Herstellerschlüsselnummer','inkl. Kilometer');
```

Can someone tell me how do I can manage this?
and no, I cant change the HTML or the fields in MYSQL or PHP :) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to this in various ways mostly depending on the minimum browser versions you are targeting, specifically IE. jQuery obviously provides the easiest way but if you don't use its other capabilities, it is an overkill to include it just for the task. Anyway, you can use jQuery for all versions of IE:

```
$(".field_name_manufacturer_key_number .label").eq(0).text("inkl. Kilometer");
```

IE 8+ (no jQuery)

```
var element = document.querySelector(".field_name_manufacturer_key_number .label");
element.textContent = "inkl. Kilometer";
```

IE 9+ (no jQuery)

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("field_name_manufacturer_key_number")[0],
    child = parent.getElementsByClassName("label")[0];
child.textContent = "inkl. Kilometer";
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

The `replace` function *returns* the string with the replacements made, so you have to assign that to something. In your case, perhaps:

If you have just one element matching the class, you can do this:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".field_name_manufacturer_key_number");
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace('Herstellerschlüsselnummer','inkl. Kilometer');
```

(`querySelector` accepts a CSS selector. It has better support than `getElementsByClassName`, it returns the first match rather than a list, so no `[0]` needed. The equivalent that gets a list [if you want that for something else at some point] is `querySelectorAll`.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set/overwrite the innerHTML after placing it:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("field_name_manufacturer_key_number")["0"].innerHTML = 
document.getElementsByClassName("field_name_manufacturer_key_number")["0"].innerHTML.replace('Herstellerschlüsselnummer','inkl. Kilometer');
```